# Why is my Minecraft modpack flashing every color when I launch it?

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

Every time I launch my Minecraft modpack, this happens:

[image: https://youtu.be/vFnrBTfWEgY]

I can't think of anything to try to fix this

It is supposed to just start up like a normal Minecraft game, but as you can see, it doesn't

Comment: Can you provide a list of mods in that modpack?

Comment: Also make sure you have the latest version of Java installed.

Comment: Can you provide the code of the modpack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was optifine that was causing the problem

Answer (score 1):

If I'd had to hazard a guess, it seems as if a mod is using a renderer and binding/unbinding the texture map.

If you scroll through the frames in the video you posted with . and , you see that it's every second frame that has the odd texture

No artifacts one frame
[image: No artifacts]

artifacts the other frame
[image: artefacts]

The mod that might be causing this is a mod that tries to impose an overlay as a type of advertisment for it's own awesomeness, which fails on your system due to either the combination of mods, or there are multiple mods that try the same trick.

[image: possible culprit]
[image: another logo]

I don't particulary know this mod or that logo, but check your mod list if there's a mod that has the similar behavior, and field a bug report to the mod author, or check if there's a setting to disable the logo displaying.

My theory is that it might be a simple case that the mod forgets to rebind the original texturemap that's needed for the rendering of the guis, which causes the render cycle that follows to glitch out due to texture coordinates being remapped on another texture. The next render cycle everything is rebound again, and then it happens from the start again